# Best collection for same amount of add,read and delete in multi threading where one thread adding and other thread reading,deleting from same storage

Tags: java

I want to store data (which mostly will be done one by one by single thread). 
Then I want to fetch the stored data and if found delete that from storage after coping the found object for local use. This operations (read and delete) will be done by multiple threads where each thread will do it multiple times (as each thread will execute many steps and each step requires reading from storage and if found delete that found object after taking copy. For each thread this reading and deleting i.e. execution of steps will be sequential.).

Currently I have created hashmap (String,CopyOnWriteArrayList) for storing the values as similar key can contain multiple related values.

For each key the CopyOnWriteArrayList object can store more than 200000 values. So minimum 200000 write and delete will be done and before deleting the value need to be fetched from the list based on matching condition.

As read and fetch+delete done separately so I cannot lock / synchronise the list at one place.

The performance get slower when the number of write,read and delete becomes higher and I think this is mainly due to use of CopyOnWriteArrayList.

Imp: Number of keys will be very less compare to the values(list size) for each key. e.g. There can be 10 keys but each key can contain 100000 values in list.

Please suggest best alternate.

## Here is the code

storeMessage method is called by only one thread but method retrieveMessage is used by multiple threads.

```
private static Map<String, MessageCache> cacheMap = new HashMap<String, MessageCache>();
public void storeMessage(MyObject message) {
    MessageCache messageCache = null;
    synchronized (cacheMap) {
                    if (cacheMap.containsKey(cacheIdentifier)) {
                        messageCache = cacheMap.get(cacheIdentifier);
                    } else {
                        messageCache = new MessageCache(isTrue);
                        cacheMap.put(cacheIdentifier, messageCache);
                    }
                }
    messageCache.storeMessage(message);
}

public MyObject retrieveMessage(MyObject searchMessage) {
    if (cacheMap.containsKey(cacheIdentifier)) { //cacheIdentifier is the key
            return cacheMap.get(cacheIdentifier).retrieveMessage(searchMessage);
    }
}

private class MessageCache {
    private List<MyObject> messageList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<MyObject>();
        private boolean requestCache;

        public MessageCache(boolean requestCache) {
            this.requestCache = requestCache;
        }
        public void storeMessage(MyObject message) {
            messageList.add(message);
        }
        public MyObject retrieveMessage(MyObject searchMessage) {
            if (requestCache) { 
                    try {
                        synchronized(this){//This has been done to avoid getting same values from the list
                            for (MyObject storedMessage : messageList) {
                                if (match) {
                                    messageList.remove(storedMessage);
                                    return storedMessage;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }catch (Exception e) {}
            }else{
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a concurrent queue (e.g. [`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html)) is what you want, but your question isn't very clear

Comment: I think you need some sort of BlockingQueue implementation. Please check the following blog of jenkov to identify which implementation suits you best. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/blockingqueue.html#blockingqueue-implementations

Comment: Have you done some research on the subject [Java Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

Answer (score 1):

According to what you're telling, sounds like a concurrent queue instead of the HashMap(like [LinkedBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) or (which I think it would work better) [`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html)) fit best there.

First of all, create a new class which contains two private variables:

```
class maps{

private String key;

private MessageCache data;

maps(String key, MessageCache data){

    this.data = data;

    this.key = key;

}

public String getKey() {
    return key;
}

public MessageCache getData() {
    return data;
}}
```

Then, use this class in the CurrentLinkedQueue: `CurrentLinkedQueue<maps> clq = new  CurrentLinkedQueue<>();`.

In order to get the key use:

```
Iterator<maps> i = clq.iterator();

    while(i.hasNext()){

        maps m = i.next();

        m.getKey(); //use the String varible this statement return in the part of your code where you need to process the key.
                    //if you need to remove that element use i.remove();


    }
```

Other solution would be to create the CurrentLinkedQueue and use as a key the Index of the collection.

As a sidenote, check out [Java Concurrency explanations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/). It might help you understand why is better to use that type of collection and how concurrency works in Java.

Comment: @cnk check it out now. If It doesn't work, post the error and I'll solve it

Comment: If you elaborate the code little more then will be very helpful. I am mainly looking for alternative (in place of CopyOnWriteArrayList) for storing the values (based on key) and deleting them after retrieval (retrieve based on key).

Comment: @cnk check it out now. If you need something just tell me!